# Excel: How to create an static reference to a cell?

Tags: excel, static

In excel, I have created the next simple formula in the cell B1: 
=A1

Therefore, the cell B1 allways is showing the content of A1

If I cut the cell A1, and paste in A5, automatically, the formula of B1 changes from =A1 to =A5.

I want to create an static reference to A1, forever, with no automatic changes.

Comment: Do not use cut.  Just copy and past then clear A1.  If you Cut you are telling Excel you want to move the references.

Comment: This is the hard of the question: how to avoid this if I really want to CUT instead COPY then clear?.

Comment: Then @kd. answer will do what you want.

Comment: Yes, it solves my problem. Thank you in any case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a static reference, use `=INDIRECT("A1")`. Indirect turns the address into a string and then refers to it.

Comment: This is not solving the problem. Ok, in B1 I will place =$A$1. then, if I cut the cell A1 and paste to A5, automatically, my formula in B1 will change from =$A$1 to =$A$5. I want to avoid this.

Comment: Great! this is the function I was searching. Thank you (my vote for you will appear as soon as I reach 15 of reputation)

Comment: FWIW: Indirect is a volatile function, to avoid the volatility they can use `=INDEX(A:A,1)`

Comment: Volatile Functions recalc every time excel recalcs regardless it the underlying data changes or not.  Non Volatile functions only calculates when the underlying data changes. @Josías

Comment: Thank you very much Scott Craner , really, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `=$A$1` so neither `A` nor `1` will be changed :-)